# How does angular pickup on services with are specified using directory/Folder paths?

Tags: javascript, angular

I was just going through the ngx-admin code on github and came across the following code in the header.ts file:

[See here](https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin/blob/master/src/app/%40theme/components/header/header.component.ts#L3)

```
import { NbMenuService, NbSidebarService } from '@nebular/theme';
```

Now when i run this project locally and run `npm install` after all dependencies have been installed and i move to the folder `@nebular/theme` i don't see any service files also `@nebular/theme` seems a path to a directory vs a path to a service , how does angular pickup on these services ?

Comment: When you are import the NbModule those files are loaded

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/glossary#barrel